# Telegram and Skype replacements for voice chat groups with no limits on Windows

Tags: chat, voice

I am looking for Telegram and Skype replacements for voice chat groups with no limits on Windows.

"No limits" means I want to join some public groups for chat.

It seems Telegram and Skype don't support public groups to find and join chats anymore.

I tried some apps like Viber, but most of them need a phone device for registration.